# Python Popen: are the pipes in blocking mode? how can I put them in non-blocking mode?

Tags: python, pipe, blocking, popen, nonblocking

In the [subprocess documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html), I haven't found any hint if the pipes created by `PIPE` are blocking or non-blocking.

I.e., if I call `p.stdout.read()`, will it block in certain circumstances? The documentation warns about that. How can I avoid that?

Using `p.communicate()` is not an option for me because I don't want to block/wait until process has exited.

The only option I see right now is to create another thread and to code some simple non-blocking file-like wrapper object. However, this seems very complicated for such simple task.